# What is `Nullable<T>?`?

Tags: c#, nullable

I made a typo and Visual Studio didn't mark it as an error:

`void Method(Nullable<SpriteFont>? font = null) { }`

`font` shows up as `SpriteFont??` in output. What did I just do?

**UPD:** Sorry, everyone, I didn't try co compile it, it just didn't show up as an error until I did. Still, it's weird that it looked as `Type??` in output.

Furthermore `SpriteFont` is already nullable, so I was going to get an error anyway :(

Comment: You defined your font as Nullable<Nullable<SpriteFont>>

Comment: I thought types accepting null values could not be made nullable... like classes.

Comment: @manman: put that as an answer

Comment: @Miguel Angelo: is there `not` predicate for generics constraints? If not - how would it be possible to constrain it?

Comment: `Nullable<T>` struct is a special type... it is handled in different ways both by C# compiler, and by the CLR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried it here, just now... and I could not reproduce what you sayd.

All of the following statements fail to compile:

- `Nullable<int>? a = 1;`
- `Nullable<Nullable<int>> b = 1;`
- `Nullable<int?> a = 1;`
- `void A(Nullable<Nullable<int>> a)`
- `void A(Nullable<int>? a)`
- `void A(Nullable<int?> a)`

Using Visual Studio 2012, C# 4 or 5 I think, .Net framework 4.5.

Comment: @Vulcan: No, I think it's an answer, because the question seems wrong as-is.

Comment: @Vulcan: No answer exists for a wrong questions, or false statements... just counter examples.

Comment: This is actually an answer. And when answers basically say "I have no idea how you got what you did", the question is usually the problem :)

Answer (score 4):

The editor's syntax checker failed to flag it as an error with the red squiggles.  Not the compiler.

Two distinct chunks of code.  They have to be, syntax checking code while you are typing it in, in essence always broken, requires a very different approach.

Comment: This is the only explanation! It also means that the question was made without actually compiling the code.